# How to understand the meaning of this ActiveStorage Error Log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

This log makes the majority of my error log on Heroku and I don't quite understand the meaning of the error. What is it and how can I make it go away?

```
2018-12-09T00:22:21.020684+00:00 app[web.3]: 00:22:21 worker.1 | E, [2018-12-09T00:22:21.016292 #15] ERROR -- : Retrying ActiveStorage::PurgeJob in 3 seconds, due to a StandardError. The original exception was #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=2>.
2018-12-09T00:22:21.020807+00:00 app[web.3]: 00:22:21 worker.1 | I, [2018-12-09T00:22:21.018923 #15]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: e89af631-9c28-4247-8897-887a55c68b64) to Sidekiq(default) at 2018-12-09 00:22:24 UTC
2018-12-09T00:22:25.744836+00:00 app[web.4]: 00:22:25 worker.1 | D, [2018-12-09T00:22:25.744555 #15] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-12-09T00:22:25.745100+00:00 app[web.4]: 00:22:25 worker.1 | E, [2018-12-09T00:22:25.744923 #15] ERROR -- : Retrying ActiveStorage::PurgeJob in 3 seconds, due to a StandardError. The original exception was #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=2>.
2018-12-09T00:22:25.746754+00:00 app[web.4]: 00:22:25 worker.1 | I, [2018-12-09T00:22:25.746542 #15]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: e89af631-9c28-4247-8897-887a55c68b64) to Sidekiq(default) at 2018-12-09 00:22:28 UTC
```

All I understand is that it is looking for an image on S3 that doesn't exist. Where does it get the value of id from?

This makes 95% of our logs and its distracting us from focusing or discovering real issues. How can i fix it and make it go away?

My ActiveStorage::Blob at this moment is empty, but it keeps asking for urls to attachment that doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: The `Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=2` part suggests that you're doing a `purge_later` on an ActiveStorage attachment twice. Or doing a `purge_later` and a `purge` on a single attachment.

Comment: What is the meaning of purge?? How do we manage it? The goal is to completely remove this from our logs.

Comment: Are you familiar with ActiveStorage? The `purge` method removes the file from S3 (or whatever storage backend you're using), `purge_later` is the same but enqueues an ActiveJob task to do the purging. So, are you calling `purge` anywhere? Are you deleting anything with attachments? Do you only have the one job stuck in the queue that's trying to purge something that's already gone?

Comment: Yea, it is trying to purge something that is already gone. I deleted the file and folder directly inside S3 dashboard. I didn’t know it could have any effect. But then when I saw that this was happening I create a file with exactly the same name, but this didn’t fix it. Probably because the randomly generated id of that file that was deleted remains unchanged and active storage continues to look for it.

Comment: That makes sense. You should be safe manually deleting the job entry to make it go away.

Comment: Please, how do I delete the Job entry?

Comment: Depends on the backend AFAIK. With delayed job you can delete the offending entry from the `delayed_jobs` table, not sure about other backends.